# How can I remove the SIM lock from my Samsung Galaxy S Blaze 4G T-Mobile?

Tags: sim-unlocking

I got an Galaxy S Blaze 4G as a gift from USA. The phone is locked and did not accept any SIM card in my country (just for T-mobile). Instead it ask for a unlock code.

Ts there any software way to unlock the phone (maybe with help of root)?

Comment: This is really not about Android at all. This is about the phone part of a Smartphone which runs Android

Answer (score 2):

T-Mobile Support page contains a thread that covers your issue:

## [SIM Unlock your phone](http://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-1588)

<sup>*Last updated on: Jul 3, 2013 2:43 PM*</sup>

> If you purchased an eligible device, the device has been programmed with a SIM Subsidy lock that will prevent the device from operating with other compatible wireless telephone carrier’s services.
>
> If you wish to use the device with the service of another wireless telephone carrier, you must enter a numeric SIM Subsidy unlock code to unlock the device.
>
> ## Understanding SIM Unlock Requirements
>
> As an active or former T-Mobile customer, you may request a phone unlock. T-Mobile will unlock your phone (as long it is not reported as lost, stolen, or blocked) if:
>
> - You have purchased your device from T-Mobile or an authorized T-Mobile dealer and activated it on T-Mobile service;
> - You have Postpaid service, have not requested an unlock code in the last 90 days;
> - You paid for your device in full;
> - Your account is in good standing;
> - You have a minimum of 40 consecutive days of active Postpaid service since purchase (or for Prepaid service, have used your device within the past 60 days );
> - You are under a 24-month service contract, you have made monthly payments for at least 18 consecutive months on your plan or have paid a migration fee for the device;  certain exceptions may apply please call Customer Care for details;
> - You are on a Prepaid plan, you have had more than $50 in total refills on the device;
> - You are a former customer, your account balance is zero and you did not port out a line associated with the device during the buyer’s remorse period;
> - You provide proof of purchase if T-Mobile is unable to verify purchase.
>
> **Note:** Exceptions to some or all requirements may apply in certain circumstances, including for Military Personnel and Business and Government Accounts.

If you qualify for the above list, [give them a call](http://support.t-mobile.com/community/contact_us) and they will help you out!

## Success Case:

A user from XDA Developers forum answered to a problem similar to your own, you can read about it [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=41289963&postcount=8):

> I just unlocked mine a few days ago. If you meet the requirements you should be fine, http://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-1588
>
> I bought my phone from ebay from a guy in Florida (I'm in NY), I had it on my account for a few months. So I had no reciept or anything, or history of the phone. When I called they asked for my phone number, account passcode, the phones model name and IMEI. Then I gave them my email, and recieved the code via email in about 24hrs. So it was pretty painless and free.

## Alternatives:

There's a XDA Developers Thread with lots of users claiming to have successfully unlocked their devices either by changing their IMEI or by means of truth manipulation:

- [Answer #4:](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=39615817&postcount=4)

  > Yup. I got mine unlocked through T-Mobile for free. Just tell them that your going to travel during soon or something and they'll give you a pin in about 15 days.
- [Answer #10](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=41315506&postcount=10):

  > FWIW I've successfully sim unlocked my T-Mobile Galaxy Blaze at the cost of  ERASING THE IMEI!

  The step by step is found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2024514):

  > Turn off the phone. Insert a SIM from another provider into your phone.
  >
  > Click "DISMISS" on the Enter Unlock Code screen after the phone starts up.
  >
  > Wait a minute for the phone to power on and settle down.
  >
  > Go to the dialer screen. Enter `*#197328640#`
  >
  > The screen will change to the hidden menu as soon as you hit the last # key in the dailer
  >
  > press <kbd>1</kbd> DEBUG SCREEN
  >   Press <kbd>8</kbd> PHONE CONTROL
  >   Press <kbd>5</kbd> SIMULATION
  >   Press <kbd>6</kbd> NETWORK LOCK
  >   Press <kbd>3</kbd> PERSO SHA256 OFF
  >   Wait exactly 30 seconds
  >   press the menu key on the phone and select back option. This will take you back to NETWORK LOCK screen.
  >   Press <kbd>4</kbd> NW LOCK NV DATA INITIALLIZ
  >   Wait exactly one minute and reboot the phone.
  >   Your phone should be unlocked.
  >   I tried this on T-989 UVLE1 original ROM with root ON.
  >   I haven't tested it on any other version or ROMs or any other phones.
  >
  > Disclaimer: I am not responsible for anything you do with your phone.

Read the entire thread [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2203808).

Answer (score 0):

I used [Ultimate Simlock Code Generator](http://hack-methods.com/ultimate-simlock-code-generator/) to unlock my phone.

Comment: Does not work with Japanese phones.